# Way to do validation through SpringData MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, validation, mongodb, spring-data

Is there any way to do validation like NotNull, Size, etc through SpringData librarirs for MongoDB?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22583492/343802

Answer (score 3):

As I'm sure you know, a lot of MongoDB validation has to be enforced in the software layer, since the database itself is [schemaless](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/119945109/why-schemaless). However, I don't think that validation is part of SpringData.

We'd need to know more about what technologies you're using in order to give a specific recommendation for how to do validation. Still, here are a few options (it looks like [you're already familiar with some of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756768/annotations-from-javax-validation-constraints-not-working)):

- If you're using Spring already, then consider using their [validation API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html). For example, it supports the JSR-303 Bean Validation API, which can be a nice way to declare the validation constraints in the javabeans themselves.
- There's also the [javax.validation Bean Validation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html) framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MongoEventListeners + JSR 303 validation for that. I described how to do it on my [blog](http://maciejwalkowiak.pl/blog/2012/04/20/jsr-303-validation-with-spring-data-mongodb/)

Comment: JSR 303 is built in Spring Data MongoDB since version 1.1.0

Comment: Your blog is not reachable @Maciej