# How to I get Spring-Data-MongoDB to validate my objects?

Tags: mongodb, bean-validation, spring-data-mongodb, spring-boot

I have a very simple Spring Boot application that uses Spring-Data-Mongodb

All I want to do is set a JSR-303 validation rule that says the object I'm saving must have a username. I read that JSR-303 was added to spring-data-mongodb in version 1.1 so I assumed that when I save an object it's validated but this isn't the case.

Does anyone have a simple example setup that shows how this works?

My User pojo looks like

```
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotNull(message = "User Name is compulsory")
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public User() {}

    public String getId() {
      return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
      return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
      this.userName = userName;
    }


    public String getPassword() {
      return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = PasswordAuthService.hash(password);
    }
}
```

I saw somewhere that validation only kicks in if you have a validator created in the context so I tried updating my Application class (which contains all the configuration, to look like

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public Validator getValidator() {
      LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
      return validator;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First make sure that you have JSR-303 validator on classpath, for example:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

If you use Java config, the way to go is to create 2 beans:

```java
@Bean
public ValidatingMongoEventListener validatingMongoEventListener() {
    return new ValidatingMongoEventListener(validator());
}

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
```

Voilà! Validation is working now.

Comment: @ZacTolley and you don't provide a link to the article?

Answer (score 5):

Starting with Spring Boot 2.3 the spring-boot-starter-validation dependency has to be added in `pom.xml` (for Maven):

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

Declaring a validator bean is not necessary.

Comment: I have this dependency but validation for Mongo doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `Validator` to the context is a good first step, but I don't think it will interact with anything unless you ask it to. The Spring Data guys can probably say for sure but I think you need to explicitly declare some listeners as well. There's an [old blog on the feature](http://maciejwalkowiak.pl/blog/2012/04/20/jsr-303-validation-with-spring-data-mongodb/), but you can find that by googling as easily as I can.

If you think there would be a useful autoconfig feature in [Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot), feel free to make a detailed proposal on github.

Comment: I saw that blog entry, but I also saw that the guy who wrote that then was asked by the Spring team to merge the work he did back into the core Spring-Data-Mongodb project.

Comment: I see that. But don't you still need to add a bean of type  `ValidatingMongoEventListener`?

Comment: I am the guy. Indeed this change was integrated in version 1.1.0 and at that time, using xml configuration for Spring Data MongoDB, validation worked out of the box.

@DaveSyer - I think it should be actually a feature in Spring Data MongoDB project rather than Spring Boot - in similar way as EnableMongoRepositories and EnableMongoAuditing are implemented

Comment: That sounds about right. Maybe we can discuss that in [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb)?

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I add

```
public User addUser(@RequestBody  @Valid User newUser, 
                   BindingResult bindingResult) throws Exception {

  if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    throw new Exception("Validation Error");
  }
```

To my controller this validates the incoming json against my rules, though I should still try and setup the validatingMongoEventListener to intercept any other parts of my code that attempt to update the model with invalid data.