# MongoDb auditing is not working

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using Spring Data MongoDb for backend storage and want to enable mongo auditing and it doesn't work not sure why.

I have next configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"base.package"})
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class DomainConfig {

}
```

And I have few entities that extend my base class:

```
@Getter
public class Entity implements Persitable {

    @Id
    @Setter
    protected String id;

    @CreatedDate
    @Setter
    protected Long creationTime;

    @LastModifiedDate
    protected Long modificationTime;

    @Version
    @Setter
    protected Long version;

    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isNew() {
        return `getVersion() == 0` && getCreationTime() == null;
    }
}
```

But when I'm calling `entityRepository.save(entity)` I'm getting `NullPointerException` on line with `getVersion() == 0` and `getVersion()` returns `null` but I think it should return `0`.

What could be the problem here?

Btw: I'm using Spring Data MongoDb 1.5.2.RELEASE version

Comment: What is `isNew()` used for ? Why is repository's save method accessing this method ?

Comment: If you check the code of spring's SimpleMongoRepository you find there line with entityInformation.isNew(entity) and that line calls isNew method of my entity.

Comment: Yeah I see it. Let me understand this.  `AbstractEntityInformation` does have default implementation for `isNew()` and you are trying to provide new implementation based on auditing fields correct ?

Comment: Method is not called if your entity is not extending Persistable interface. So I've implemented it and provided new implementation based on auditing fields.

Comment: Why there is no @ Document annotation. Remove implements Persistable and isNew(). Add @ Document on class and try once.

Comment: It has @Document. For now I've fixed it with Long version = 0L;

Comment: @Orest Did you actually [enable validation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22583492/5873923)?

Comment: @Marc do I need validation for mongo auditing?

Comment: I should have wrote "Did you try to enable validation?"... I'm not a 100% sure it is needed with the `@LastModifiedDate` and `@CreationDate` validation annotation, but for instance `@NotNull`, `@NotBlank`, `@NotEmpty` requires validation in order to work. It's worth a shot.