# Can annotations limit the characters of a class field in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, java-annotations

I'm using java 1.8, Spring Boot and MongoDb to store some data in database to learn about mongoDb

I want to limit the characters of a class fields through annotations i tried to control this with hibernate-validator:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;

@Document(collection = "MusicGroup")
public class MusicGroup {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Size(min = 7, max = 7, message = "title need to have only 4 characters")
    @Field("Title")
    private String title;
    @Size(min = 11, max = 11, message = "type need to have only 11 characters")
    @Field("Type")
    private String type;
    @Field("Members")
    private List<String> members;

    public MusicGroup(String titulo, String tipo, List<String> integrantes) {
        this.title = titulo;
        this.type = tipo;
        this.members = integrantes;
    }
```

but when i insert this into mongodb whit this code:

```
@Service
public class MusicGroupServiceImpl implements MusicGroupService {

    @Autowired
    private MusicGroupRepository repository;

    public MusicGroupServiceImpl() {

    }

    @Override
    public void storeGroup(){

        String[] memberList = new String[3];
        memberList[0] = "A";
        memberList[1] = "B";
        memberList[2] = "C";

        MusicGroup group = new MusicGroup("Panteraaaaaa", "Heavy Metallllllllllllllll", memberList);

        repository.save(group);

    }

}
```

it does works without any problems when Panteraaaaaa have a length greater than 7 and Heavy Metallllllllllllllll the same

I attach the following code that corresponds to my pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

To realize the question
is possible to control de length of characters of fields in java through annotations ? or i need to do a method to control this

Comment: Can you have a try if the accepted answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568962/how-to-i-get-spring-data-mongodb-to-validate-my-objects also works for you?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the acepted question is not exactly the solution for my problem but it guided me, i will put in few minutes what i did to validate the size of the fields

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hello everyone i finally found the solution to the validation size of the fields

I only needed to do a new class here the code:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.ValidatingMongoEventListener;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Configuration {

    @Bean
    public ValidatingMongoEventListener validatingMongoEventListener() {
        return new ValidatingMongoEventListener(validator());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

then change the place of the size annotation to the setter

```
@Document(collection = "MusicGroup")
public class MusicGroup {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field("Title")
    private String title;
    @Field("Type")
    private String type;
    @Field("Members")
    private String[] members;

    public MusicGroup() {
    }

    @Size(min = 7, max = 7)
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @Size(min = 11, max = 11)
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    // Other getters, setters and to String()

}
```

add to the pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

and when i create a new object MusicGroup:

```
String[] memberList = new String[3];
memberList[0] = "typeA";
memberList[1] = "typeB";
memberList[2] = "typec";

MusicGroup grupo = new MusicGroup();

grupo.setType("888888888889");
grupo.setTitle("hhhhhhh");
grupo.setIntegrantes(memberList);

musicaService.storeGroup(grupo);
```

if you do this when you run the program it will give a exception like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:779) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at es.cic.cmunoz.MongoDbMascotaApplication.main(MongoDbMascotaApplication.java:32) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: null
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.ValidatingMongoEventListener.onBeforeSave(ValidatingMongoEventListener.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ...
```

but if you put a valid String in this method

```
grupo.setType("88888888888");
```

it wont give you any excepion

Thanks to [dunni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465223/dunni) for his comment , it guided me to the solution

PD: if you want to validate a number field like a int you need to use @Max(Number) or @Min(Number) in getter methods

See this documentation for more details: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-message-interpolation.html#section-resource-bundle-locator

to add custom messages: https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2014/07/26/including-field-value-in-validation-message-using-spring-validation-framework-for-jsr-303/

Answer (score 1):

You are not validating the object.  Just giving restrictions.  Can you make your method to get object like below and try again?

```
storeGroup (@Validated MusicGroup group) {
....
}
```

Edit: check for @Validated and @Valid annotations.

Comment: I am sorry, the @Validated tag doesnt work for me, it allowed me to store in the database a not valid object