# @NotNull not working as expected

Tags: java

I have a method like:

```
public String getParamValue(@NotNull String param) {
        .......
        .......
        .......
    }
```

Even after putting `@NotNull` in-front of the `param`, whenever i am calling `getParamValue(null)` it is not throwing `NPE`. It proceeds as normal, do i need to do something else or am i using it wrongly? Thanks.

I am using Java 7 and `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` if it helps in any ways.

Comment: Which NonNull Annotation are you using?

Comment: javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

Comment: Is this code running in a container or as a standalone program?

Answer (score 3):

This annotation doesn't do anything by itself. It is just a mark for other tools, so they know the constraints. The tools that checks it are source code analyzers and validation tools.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a garantee for notnull, its more like a promise. so you could do a preconditions check:

```
if (param == null) {
    throw new PreconditionExc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this question has already been asked before. 
To summarize you will need to do this:

MVC namespace configuration for annotations:

The JSR-303 spec JAR: validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar (looks like you already have that)

An implementation of the spec, such as Hibernate Validation, which appears to be the most commonly used example: hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar
you could also use one of these
https://code.google.com/p/gwt-validation/ and
http://bval.apache.org/

In the bean to be validated, validation annotations, either from the spec JAR or from the implementation JAR (which you have already done)

In the handler you want to validate, annotate the object you want to validate with @Valid, and then include a BindingResult in the method signature to capture errors.

[Annotations from javax.validation.constraints not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756768/annotations-from-javax-validation-constraints-not-working)

Comment: I am not using hibernate so any other implementation can i use to get it working? Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my answer with alternatives to hibernate validator, best of luck.