# Javax Validation Size annotation does not behave correctly

Tags: java, validation, annotations

So I have a simple class like this:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Temail {

    @Size(min = 0, max = 10)
    private String json;

    public Temail(String json) {
        Validate.notEmpty(json, "json can't be empty");
        setJson(json);
    }

    public void setJson(String json) {
        this.json = json;
    }

    public String getJson() {
        return json;
    }

}
```

What I am expecting is if I run `new Temail("1234123123123");` I expect it to throw an exception but it does not. I looked at the conventions and it does fit into the right convention. So what's the problem here?

Comment: Could you please include your import statements.  There are lots of different validators and you might be mixing them.

Comment: Are you using this [@size](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html)?

Comment: @dramzy yes I am using that one

Comment: maybe Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756768/annotations-from-javax-validation-constraints-not-working

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not supposed to throw an exception when a constraint is invalid. Instead, you use a validator instance to validate the fields based on the constraints you define. So, something like this:

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

Temail t = new Temail("123456789012345");

Set<ConstraintViolation<Temail>> constraintViolations = validator.validateProperty(t, "json");
```

See more examples and explanations [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html).

Comment: That's fine I guess, but what if we had 10 fields? Are there any automatic way to validate that?

Comment: Validate the object instead:
`validator.validate(t)`