# BindingResult always return 0 errors Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, model-view-controller

I have problem with Hibernate Validator or more precisely with BindingResult and method .hasError(). It return always true even with null object. Check my code here: https://github.com/jeddyn/spring-mvc-demo

```
Customer: null customer first name: null
bindingresult: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors
Customer: null customer first name: null
bindingresult: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
     <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0.GA</version> 
</dependency>
```

You can change the version compatible with hibernate validators.

Put `@Valid` before `@ModelAttribute` by changing order like below, weird but it works.

```
public String processForm(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer,
            BindingResult theBindingResult)
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8758577/6572971)

Comment: Already i have this in my project but still not working. I tried: add bean `<bean id="myBeansValidator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />` and add `<mvc:annotation-driven validator="myBeansValidator"/>`
But now i have error: https://pastebin.com/UwWHt2Rc

Comment: change the order of both

Comment: Still nothing, also i tried delete folder .m2 with repository and reimport it.

Comment: what version of validation api you are using

Comment: javax.validation version 2.0.1.Final, Hibernate Validator 6.0.7.Final

Comment: can you check with hibernate validator also latest only 6.0.13.Final

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>   it works for me

Comment: I create new project with all the same and now it's working fine. I don't know what was wrong. Thank you guys for help!

Comment: Try upvote get and accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

For me it works this way:

```java
    @PostMapping("/registration/post")
    public String processRegistrationForm(@ModelAttribute("registrationForm") @Valid RegistrationForm registrationForm, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request, RedirectAttributes redirectAt) {...}
```

Before `bindingResult` was always `0` because I had forget to add `spring-boot-starter-validation` the `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```