# Bean validation annotation (@Size)not working properly

Tags: java, jpa, bean-validation

```
import org.javers.core.metamodel.annotation.DiffIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Set;


@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class ProjectComponent extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 128)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "project_name", nullable = false)
    private String projectName;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    @Size(max = 512, message
            = "Cannot exceed 512 characters")
    private String name;
}
```

@Size(max=512) I used this in the entity field but whenever I crossed size 512 then this thing should stop on that particular field should not persist into DB and that means should not throw an exception from DB.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756768/annotations-from-javax-validation-constraints-not-working

Comment: I run into the same problem. What was the solution?

Answer (score 2):

As `ProjectComponent` is an Entity class, I recommend you should use `@Length` annotation or add `length` attribute in `@Column` annotation. I found this article online which explains the difference between these @Size & @Length annotations. Please take a look. [Difference between @Size & @Length](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-size-length-column-differences).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use @Size and @Valid together.

Answer (score 0):

```
@PrePersist
@PostLoad
void markNotNew() {
    Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<AbstractEntity>> constraintViolations =
            validator.validate( this );
    constraintViolations.size();
    if(!constraintViolations.isEmpty()) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException(constraintViolations.stream().map(ConstraintViolation::getMessage).collect(Collectors.joining()));
    }
        this.isNew = false;
}
```

got the solution thanks friends.